# How to remove the shade of markers in rviz?

Tags: ros, rviz, points, markers, visualization-msgs

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone. I am visualizing about 100000 marker points in rviz. Due to the shade (or shadow) of markers and small size of points, the color of points is not clearly visible. Is there any way to remove the shade of marker points?

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38478/how-to-remove-the-shade-of-markers-in-rviz?/) by [Ali Abdul Khaliq](https://answers.ros.org/users/414/ali-abdul-khaliq/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2012-07-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-07-10**:
What do you mean by "shade"?

**Comment by [Ali Abdul Khaliq](https://answers.ros.org/users/414/ali-abdul-khaliq/) on 2012-07-10**:
Maybe its batter to call it shadow of markers (cubes or points).

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-07-10**:
Do you mean the alpha channel (transparency)?

**Comment by [Ali Abdul Khaliq](https://answers.ros.org/users/414/ali-abdul-khaliq/) on 2012-07-10**:
No its not the alpha channel. I have added the following screen short where the shadow of points are creating magnetic field like pattern. I want to remove this pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try zooming in or out. Those look like aliasing issues (likely due to the small size of your markers).

For a more detailed explanation, take a look at the description of the [Moiré pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moir%C3%A9_pattern)

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2012-07-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1